# Reactjs : production environment : net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: php, reactjs, linux, https, rest

For Reactjs application I have deploy it on linux server and it is working for example http://00.0.000.00

I am using apis(PHP) to get data , that apis are also on same server and working on https://00.0.000.00

while fetch data from api it gives error in console.

```
API_URL net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

Please guide me how to resolve issue.

please let me know if required any other information because I am very new to this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

**ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID** is one of the SSL(Security Socket Layers) connection Error i.e SSL common name mismatch error.

Reason for the Err:

1. It can be caused due to misconfiguration of certificate in a server.
2. Due to third-party extensions.
3. Or System Anti-virus or firewall security programs

Ways to debug:

1. Check if system date and time are properly set.
2. Try to remove/uninstall third party extension which is causing this err.
3. Check for Antivirus/firewall.
4. Look for the correct configuration of your SSL certificate.
5. Make sure you are addressing to appropriate IP Address.

This might help to get your issue resolve.